# Wordpress link management

Tags: links

So I just started using Wordpress. I am using the site to write reviews and link to other sites.

I am trying to figure out a better way to manage links, I will be writing a blog post and referencing a link to another site. This same link might be on multiple blog posts. Is there a way to easily create a reference to this link and manage it at one location instead of updating each blog post if the link should change in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single wordpress page with a PHP or meta redirect to the final URL.  Then each of your blog posts would link to that single page.  It would work, but I reckon that once you got past about 50 or so outgoing link pages it would get pretty hard to manage easily.

A better alternative as it would be more managable would be some customised PHP and a database - but it is obviously more complex.  You would put the outgoing link in the database and then display the contents of that database record in each blog post where you want to show that outgoing link.  Doing that you would have an admin area to edit links in the database.